# Solr Search Query dates (stored in text fields)

Tags: solr, lucidworks

I’m using Lucence Solr (Lucid works ) for search  to index and its  a schema less search engine to index outlook files.

I have been using it since version 2.0.* and have an issue with querying dates.

The older versions were mapping( date_created, mail from_date etc) to date datatype making date range queries easier.

After upgrading to version 3.0*  all the date fields are mapped to text_general  data type .
All my queries for dates are failing.

Please help !!! Any  helpful resources are greatly appreciated as I’m a newbie.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you actually using? Lucidworks Fusion or Solr?

Comment: LucidWorks... assuming the API query is internally using Solr.

Comment: But the configuration etc. will depend on Fusion. I'd ask this question in LWs support groups if available.